# Changing line width and color in raphael.js

Tags: javascript, css, raphael

Please bear with me I just started using the raphael.js library and I need to change the width and color of the line. 
I looked at the documentation and other answers on here but I'm totally lost. 
At the moment it is too thin and I need it to be of another color as well. 
[image]

**Codes**

```
function Line(startX, startY, endX, endY, raphael) {
            var start = {
                x: startX,
                y: startY
            };
            var end = {
                x: endX,
                y: endY
            };
            var getPath = function() {
                return "M" + start.x + " " + start.y + " L" + end.x + " " + end.y;
            };
            var redraw = function() {
                node.attr("path", getPath());
            }

            var node = raphael.path(getPath());
            return {
                updateStart: function(x, y) {
                    start.x = x;
                    start.y = y;
                    redraw();
                    return this;
                },
                updateEnd: function(x, y) {
                    end.x = x;
                    end.y = y;
                    redraw();
                    return this;
                }
            };
        };



        $(document).ready(function() {
            var paper = Raphael("raphaelContainer",1280,470, 0, 0);
            $("#raphaelContainer").mousedown(

                    function(e) {
                        x = e.offsetX;
                        y = e.offsetY;
                        line = Line(x, y, x, y, paper);
                        $("#raphaelContainer").bind('mousemove', function(e) {
                            x = e.offsetX;
                            y = e.offsetY;
                            line.updateEnd(x, y);
                        });
                    });

            $("#raphaelContainer").mouseup(

                    function(e) {
                        $("#raphaelContainer").unbind('mousemove');
                    });
        });
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at stroke-width and stroke.

```
element.attr({ stroke-width: 3, stroke: 'red' }); for example
```

Docs for 'attr' [here](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr)

Comment: Thanks I added this code `node.attr("stroke", "yellow");` after the initialization of node and it worked.